# How to get a report of orphaned objects?

Tags: custom-object, custom-report-type

I have a custom object, that one of it's fields is `Account` as a lookup field. And once the `Account` is deleted, the custom object is set to stay alive

[image]

Now I need to report on all these custom objects that are in the system, and do not have an account as parent.

I created a new report type, Accounts With/Without `Custom Objects` (I know that's not the way, but I had to try ^^ )

[image]

I tried to filter for Account ID = "", Account Name = ""
For neither I get any results.

Note: I have at least 16 of these keys in the system.

- I can create a report, export to excel, sort/filter, but I want to work with it in SF, to use Dashboards and Alerts abilities
- If I try to create a custom License report, I can't select Account as the `(B)` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create custom report type (unless you need fields via lookup going from License to other objects), use standard "Licenses" one.

And then simply use the "Account name equals [leave blank]" in filters.

For example here's Contacts without Account:

[image]

Comment: How on earth have I missed that ^^

Comment: Everything I'll say will be used against me :P